# some info from file is not being read

Tags: c

I'm doing this program as part of my exam grade for my computer science course. For some reason, the first time the file is read in the loop only the title and the serial number is read but info is not being stored in the other variables.

This is the file data

```
pass
qwerty
ef frgr
math
5454
1234

awesome
qazxc
fue fr
math
4354
1234
```

Code:

```
int retrieveBooks(book bookList[])
{


    int amt=0, readRes;
    FILE *bookFile;

    bookFile=fopen("Book_List.txt", "r");

    if (bookFile==NULL)
        printf("Book file not available\n\n");
    else{
        readRes=fscanf(bookFile,"%[^\n]s", bookList[amt].title); 

        while(readRes>0){
            fscanf(bookFile,"%s", bookList[amt].serialNum);
            fscanf(bookFile,"%[^\n]s", bookList[amt].author);
            fscanf(bookFile,"%[^\n]s", bookList[amt].subject);
            fscanf(bookFile,"%i", &bookList[amt].price);
            fscanf(bookFile,"%i", &bookList[amt].ownerID);

            ++amt;
            readRes=fscanf(bookFile,"%[^\n]s", bookList[amt].title);
        }// end while

        fclose(bookFile);
    }// end else

    return amt;
}// end retrieveBooks
```

Comment: Instead of `while (readRes > 0)` study the return value of `fscanf()` and you can come up with a more robust loop.

Comment: Without knowing what types these variables are or what's in the file, it's almost impossible to tell what's going on.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] including exact file contents, expected behaviour and actual behaviour.

Comment: `fscanf` with no limits on the size of the string being read can overflow your buffers. You probably want to use `fgets` + `sscanf` with limits on how long the strings can be.

Comment: You shouldn't have `s` after `$[^\n]`.

Comment: `"%[^\n]s"` --> `"%[^\n]%*c"`

Comment: please post the definition of the struct book, otherwise we have no idea about the details in the posted code.

Comment: the posted code is making the assumption that any individual data block in the input file contains all the expected fields,  This is a very risky assumption.  Suggest each call to `fscanf()` check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation is successful.

Comment: when using the `%s` or the `%[^\n]` input conversion specifiers, always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is one less than the length of the input field, to avoid any buffer overrun.  Such overrun is undefined behavior and can/will lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY,  this: `"%[^\n]%*c"` does not work correctly if the file contains DOS line endings  better to use this: `" %[^\n]". Note the leading space

Comment: to avoid repeating code, the `while()` statement would be better written as: `while(  (readRes=fscanf(bookFile," %[^\n]", bookList[amt].title) ) == 1 )`

Comment: @user3629249 It is preferable not to use `%s` or `" %[^\n]"` for line by line input. Also CRLF in DOS is converted to LF(`'\n'`).

Comment: @BLUEPIXY,  true about the method of reading line by line input,  However, this seems to be homework, so best to stay with the technique proposed by the OP.  It would be a new data (to me) when reading a file that contains DOS line endings to read the two characters and only get a single character into the program.  Back when I was working with DOS files (does that date me?) it was read as two separate characters when accessed by `scanf()`, `fgets()`, `getc()`,  etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to read a line with `fscanf()`, the syntax is

```
readRes=fscanf(bookFile,"%[^\n]", bookList[amt].title);
```

There shouldn't be `s` after `%[^\n]`, that looks for a literal `s` in the file, which will never be found because `%[^\n]` keeps reading until the next character is newline, so the next character obviously won't be `s`. I guess you thought that `[^\n]` was some kind of modifier of the `%s` format, but they're totally separate.

Also, after you read a line like this, you should read the next character to skip over the newline. Otherwise, the next call to `fscanf()` with this pattern will just read an empty string, because it stops at the same newline. You can simply put a space at the beginning of each format string to skip over whitespace first.

So the code should be:

```
    readRes=fscanf(bookFile,"%[^\n]", bookList[amt].title); 

    while(readRes>0){
        fscanf(bookFile," %s", bookList[amt].serialNum);
        fscanf(bookFile," %[^\n]", bookList[amt].author);
        fscanf(bookFile," %[^\n]", bookList[amt].subject);
        fscanf(bookFile," %i", &bookList[amt].price);
        fscanf(bookFile," %i", &bookList[amt].ownerID);

        ++amt;
        readRes=fscanf(bookFile," %[^\n]", bookList[amt].title);
    }// end while
```

Alternatively, you could read each line with `fgets()`, then use `sscanf()` to parse it as a number when necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful responses! Barmar I did what you said but the price and ownerID variables are not storing the right values (maybe garbage values)

Comment: You accepted the answer. Does that mean you solved the problem?

Comment: Yeah Barmar the problem was solved. For some reason the watch was displaying incorrect values for the integer variables: price and ownerID during debugging. Can someone tell me why?